# How can I receive alerts when files are deleted or modified?

Tags: linux, files, monitoring

I've read through how to [monitor AWS EC2 file system changes](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-monitor-file-system-changes/) using the Linux Audit system, and that all makes sense. I've also looked through the RHEL audit system documentation. I don't want to have to be constantly checking an audit report to see if a certain set of "important" files have been modified or deleted.

Is there a way to be alerted somehow when certain audit events occur? At the very least, execute a script that I can define? (Then I can do whatever I want in the script... send an email, send to CloudWatch, send to SNS, etc.)

I'm using Amazon Linux 2 EC2 instances.

Answer (score 1):

That audit system might be a bit of an overly large hammer for your nail.

A simple C, C++, go, rust,.. program which uses the [fanotify](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fanotify.7.html) functions to intercept filesystem events would probably be a bit more wieldy and could very well integrate with arbitrary alert mechanisms. As an example, there's the pyfanotify Python library, which encapsulates fanotify for a typical language in which notification libraries are often available.

Comment: Can you point me to some examples or provide one of the connection between collecting events and passing them off to an alerting system?

Comment: I don't know what kind of alerting system you're interested in! Example for using pyfanotive: in the [pyfanotify repo](https://github.com/baskiton/pyfanotify/tree/main/examples). You just go and where they handle each element of `cli.get_events()` cause whatever alert you want (make a HTTP request, send an SMS, burn a pyre…)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want **aide**

*advanced intrusion detection system*

has an `/etc/aide.conf` file which you can tailor which has email capability already built in to notify on events of file deletion, modification, etc.

Many internet articles on how to configure and use aide.

aide is a fully supported linux program... I think it is included on the RHEL install versus having to go fetch it from EPEL, so I think you should have little problem getting it on your Amazon setup.